# How to Set Params with Node Get Request

Tags: node.js, parameters, get

I am trying to make a get request using the NPM Request module and am having trouble passing in a params argument.

Going through the docs I can't tell what the correct syntax is.

```
makeRequest(req, res, num, cookie) {
  request({
    headers: {
      'Cookie': cookie
    },
    url: 'https://api.domain.com/path',
    params: num // this is incorrect
  },
  (error, response, body) => {
      res.json({
        msg: "Success"
      })
    }
  })
}
```

**How can I pass a** `params` **argument into a request?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

> qs - object containing querystring values to be appended to the uri

```
request({
    headers: {
      'Cookie': cookie
    },
    url: 'https://api.domain.com/path',
    qs: { num: 1} 
 })
```

This should create a url

```
https://api.domain.com/path?num=1
```